# multiple viewclass (Kivy - Recycleview)

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language

I'm implementing a recycleview in kivy. It is possible have multiple (one or more) viewclass depending the dataset data? i would like to have in the same list multiple layouts (eg. one line viewclass1 (one label and two buttons) and another line viewclass2 (one label and two TextInput). Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to have multiple recycleviews on one screen in kivy? If you've seen something similiar in another app, it's probably possible. Can you maybe draw how you want your kivy app to look like and post the screenshot?

Comment: Actually, i would like to have just one recycleview widget in my screen, i would like to have lines with differents viewclass. (eg. one line viewclass1 (one label and two buttons) and another line viewclass2 (one label and two TextInput) and so on. thanks.

Comment: I can't really get what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide some examples? Like if the data says "hello" there will be a button next to it? Or if it's a number there will be a TextInput? A picture with an example would be great. For now it seems like you don't really need the recycleview itself.

Comment: <viewclass2>:
    value: ''
    texto: ''
    Button:
        id: btn
        text: root.value
    TextInput:
        id: sugao
        text: root.texto
<viewclass1>:
    lblTest: ''
    Label:
        text: root.lblTest
    Switch:
        id: swc
        active: True

<Myscreen>:
 rv:
     id: recicleview
        viewclass: 'viewclass1' -->i would like alternate this field depending on the data
        RecycleBoxLayout:
         default_size: None, dp(30)
         default_size_hint: 1, None
         orientation: 'vertical'
         spacing: dp(2)

Comment: I can't make sense of that. Edit your post to include your code and format it correctly.

Comment: Sorry. ![this is i would like to do](http://s1259.photobucket.com/user/abutrevoador/media/pic_zpssyup8iia.png.html).  Each line is controlled with a viewclass depending on the data. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to do [this](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.settings.html)? Do you need help in doing that? Or do you want it to look like that but do something else?

Comment: Yes, i would like to do that. I don't know how to have lines with different viewclass, just lines with the same viewclass. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a widget that extends a layout and then you could add the widgets you need programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have lines with different `viewclasses` in a single `RecycleView`. `RecycleView` ,by design, has only one `viewclass` because it is meant for a large collection of homogeneous items.

For what you are looking for the most straightforward way is probably to use `ScrollView` and to define a custom `add_line(self, type):` function to dynamically add each line specifying the `type`.